# Use reflection to fill array of derived class with array of base class

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider following problem:
I want to fill an array of type T with values at runtime. I am able to get all the GameObjects (talking about Unity3D here) which hold one of these instances. These GameObjects are in the *results* array. The GetComponent method allows to extract the instances of T from the gameObject, but autmatically casts it to Ts base class *Component*. *blueprint* contains information about the binding target, like the FieldInfo of the array.

The current code looks like this:

```
var arrayOfBaseClass = 
    (
        from instance 
        in results 
        select instance.GetComponent(blueprint.Field.FieldType.GetElementType()))
    .ToArray();
// Missing Step here
blueprint.Field.SetValue(o, arrayOfBaseClass);
```

SetValue throws right now ArgumentException: *Object type UnityEngine.Component[] cannot be converted to target type: VEL.Input.ActionSignalReceiver[]*

Additional info *arrayOfBaseClass* is actually an array of instaces of T, just cast to the base type by GetComponent. If I knew T beforehand a manual cast to T would work and solve this problem. Sadly T is not know beforehand and may vary between different types (yet all derive from Component)

The question now is if there is a way to use the information of FieldInfo to cast the array back to its most derived type.

Comment: Do what is mentioned in the duplicate for every instance in your array and you´re done.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of linked question. First this is not about casting an arbitrary class to a base class, secondly this question is specificially asking about the reflection 'SetValue'. The classes I consume are instances of the derived class and I only need to bind them through the array via SetValue.

Comment: From your code it´s hard to see what `results`, `arrayOfDerivedClass` and also what `arrayOfBaseClass` actually are. An array doesn´t have a `Field`-property.

Comment: I rewrote and tried to clarify the points. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with some trial and error, will post relevant code below explanation.
As we are working within reflection we need a way to pass into the type of the target we want to use. In this case we can do it by constructing a generic method at runtime.

So first we declare a generic function, which takes a target object, a fieldInfo (beforehand it is checked that this is an array field) and an array of objects. These objects are cast to the target type T and then assigned to the field:

```
public void BindToTypedArray<T> (object bindingTarget, FieldInfo field, object[] values)
    {
        var typedArray = from v in values select (T)v;
        field.SetValue(bindingTarget, typedArray.ToArray());
    }
```

To call this function we need to know the type T, but reflection offers a method to created a typed generic method at runtime via *MakeGenericMethod*. So what we do in the example above is that we create a custom typed instance of the function above and feed in the object array we generated:

```
    var arrayOfBaseClass = 
        (
            from instance 
            in results 
            select instance.GetComponent(blueprint.Field.FieldType.GetElementType()))
        .ToArray();

    // NEWCODE --------------------------------------------------------
    MethodInfo bindArray= typeof(DataGlueController).GetMethod("BindToTypedArray");
    MethodInfo bindArrayTyped=bindArray.MakeGenericMethod(blueprint.Field.FieldType.GetElementType());
    bindArrayTyped.Invoke(this, new object[] { o, blueprint.Field, arrayOfBaseClass });
    // END NEWCODE ----------------------------------------------------

    // blueprint.Field.SetValue(o, arrayOfBaseClass); <- this is done in the BindToTypedArray function
```